# Using WITH clause with INSERT statement in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, with-statement, insert-into

I have a requirement in which I need to get one column from another table and insert that column data with some other data into another table.

Example:

If the cust_id='11' then I need to get the cust_code from cust table (let's say it returns cust_code='ABCD') and then use that cust_code with some other data to insert into table_1 like so:

```
WITH get_cust_code_for_cust_id AS (
    SELECT cust_code FROM cust WHERE cust_id=11
)

INSERT INTO public.table_1(
    cust_code, issue, status, created_on)
    VALUES (SELECT cust_code FROM get_cust_code_for_cust_id, 'New Issue', 'Open', current_timestamp)
```

But this query does not work as we haven't called the `get_cust_code_for_cust_id` query.

My preference is some query with `WITH` clause but any other answer will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If the source of an `insert` statement is a `select` do **not** use the `VALUES` keyword.

```
WITH get_cust_code_for_cust_id AS (
    SELECT cust_code 
    FROM cust 
    WHERE cust_id=11
)
INSERT INTO public.table_1 (cust_code, issue, status, created_on)
SELECT cust_code, 'New Issue', 'Open', current_timestamp 
FROM get_cust_code_for_cust_id;
```

You don't really need the CTE for this though:

```
INSERT INTO public.table_1 (cust_code, issue, status, created_on)
SELECT cust_code, 'New Issue', 'Open', current_timestamp  
FROM cust 
WHERE cust_id=11
```

Comment: I'd like to add a link to the docs, and especially hint to the examples at the bottom: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html

Comment: Both of the queries are working perfectly for my scenario.